# RegEx.Replace to Replace Whole Words and Skip when Part of the Word

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I am using regex to replace certain keywords from a string (or Stringbuilder) with the ones that I choose. However, I fail to build a valid regex pattern to replace only whole words.

For example, if I have InputString = "fox foxy" and want to replace "fox" with "dog" it the output would be "dog dogy".

What is the valid RegEx pattern to take only "fox" and leave "foxy"?

```
 public string Replace(string KeywordToReplace, string Replacement) /
        {

            this.Replacement = Replacement;
            this.KeywordToReplace = KeywordToReplace;

            Regex RegExHelper = new Regex(KeywordToReplace, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            string Output = RegExHelper.Replace(InputString, Replacement);

            return Output;
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884759/how-can-i-replace-a-specific-word-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regexes support a special escape sequence that represents a word boundary. Word-characters are everything in `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. So a word-boundary is between any character that belongs in this group and a character that doesn't. The escape sequence is `\b`:

```
\bfox\b
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget to put '@' symbol before your '\bword\b'.
For example:

```
address = Regex.Replace(address, @"\bNE\b", "Northeast");
```

@ symbol ensures escape character, backslash(\), does not get escaped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use boundary..

```
KeywordToReplace="\byourWord\b"
```

Comment: The funny thing is that if I use it like that it works - "\bfox\b". But when I try to create the pattern separately like "string Pattern = "\b" + Keyword + "\b" and later use it Regex.Replace(Pattern, NewKeyword) it doesn't.

Comment: Found it, it's the "@" before "\b" but I really don't know what it does there.

Comment: @GeorgievGeorgi check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)