# Regex Filter in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm creating a sort of filter for a message, but running into some trouble with actually replacing parts of the word.

After looking over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884759/how-can-i-replace-a-specific-word-in-c) question, I tried to do it almost exactly like they did. However, I want to work with multiple possible words to filter, and I want each to have a different thing to change to. A dictionary would seem to work perfectly for this. However, it does not work.

```
        Dictionary<string, string> filterWords = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"lol", "LAUGH OUT LOUD"},
            {"wtf", "WOW THAT'S FANTASTIC"},
        };

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> word in filterWords)
        {
            Regex r = new Regex(@"\b" + word.Key + "\b");
            message = r.Replace(message, word.Value);
        }
```

I don't see anything *really* wrong with the code, but it doesn't actually replace any words, and I'm stumped as to how to fix it.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: `I'm stumped as to how to fix it.` How to fix *what problem* ?

Comment: does your second \b need the @?

Comment: @Chimoo I think that would be it

Comment: Explain the problem! Theres no way to help you if you cant tell the real issue!

Comment: Maybe you should also post what you are testing it against

Comment: At first I added it inside of the "" portion of the expression, so I was wrong to say that it did not work. @Chimoo

Comment: great, so if it's fixed you should accept dasblinkenlight's answer

Comment: @Chimoo have to wait a certain time, I did it as soon as the time was up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two problems that I see with this code is that it treats message case-sensitively, and that you missed the `@` in front of the second `"\b"` literal, making `"\b"` a backspace, not an end-of-word marker.

Try replacing

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b" + word.Key + "\b");
```

with

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b" + word.Key + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

the rest of your code should work fine.

You may want to optimize your code a little by per-compiling your regexes. In addition, since `filterWords` is not really a `Dictionary`, you may want to use `List<Tuple<Regex,string>>`.

Comment: Usually, you are lucky when you forget to escape a character and get the unkown escape sequence compilation error, but if you choose one of these: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx, it will compile just fine

Comment: `@"\\b"` and `"\\b"` are different, corresponding to `\\b` and `\b` respectively. I think you want `@"\b"` or `"\\b"`, which parse to `\b`, which parses to regex's word boundary.